# UIWebView scaling page so that there is no need for horizontal scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview, scaling

Is there a way to scale a web page in a UIWebView that maintains the aspect ratio but alleviates the need to scroll horizontally to read an article, for example. Vertical scrolling is fine, I just don't want the user to have to constantly be scrolling back and forth horizontally to read each line of the article. Thanks!

Edit: the code I'm using to create the view

```
    _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[self view] frame].size.width, [[self view] frame].size.height)];
    [_webView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [_webView setDelegate:self];
    [_webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[headline link]]];
```

The link is always formatted for mobile already.

Comment: There's a property you can set. It's scalesPageToFit. You can set it with either `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES` or in IB under Web View properties.

Comment: Yeah, I have that set already, no luck.

Comment: Then there's probably some complication involved, the property always works fine for me. Show some code

Comment: Can you share the URL with us? Might be something about that mobile web site. It's strange that you'd have to do any scaling for a mobile web site, at all, because by design, you generally should never have to scroll horizontally. Could it be a problem with that mobile web site you're visiting?

Comment: It's possible. I'm loading the page in a subview of an iPad app. An example of a link is: http://m.espn.go.com/mlb/story?storyId=8133563&ex_cid=espnapi_public

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that defining the viewport for your UIWebView could help:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

this is to use the full width of the device; if your UIWebView is smaller, that you can specify its width in points.

In case you need to add the meta tag to the HTML of your page after loading it, you can use this code:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

  NSString* js = 
  @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); "
   "meta.setAttribute( 'name', 'viewport' ); "
   "meta.setAttribute( 'content', 'width = device-width' ); "
   "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)";

  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: js];        
}
```

Also check [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly) for another technique for the same.

Comment: So I should just prepend the HTML I received with that top line? What's the difference between the top and the bottom solutions?

Comment: Bottom solution allows you to do the same in case you do no control the HTML source (the server or the file you load) and need to change it "on-the-fly", i.e., after the webView has loaded it.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. However, with this particular URL, it distorts the toolbars on the top. Is there any way to just resize the article itself, rather than the entire page?

Comment: Well, this is a different kind of problem, I think. Using the same approach as above, you could override some CSS of the page toolbar, so that it fits the width... I cannot imagine any other way around it.

Comment: Should we set only in webviewDidFinishLoad method? Cant I set it as soon as I declare webview?

Comment: It depends on how you load the web view content. It surely won't work if you add the `meta` to the web view, then load it through `loadRequest:`. You could though, get the HTML from your host, then add to it the meta tag as suggested (in this case you would parse the HTML and find the right place where to put it), the use `loadHTMLString:`. Otherwise, if you are going to evaluate JS (as in my answer) you are better off by waiting for the DOM to be fully rendered (i.e., in `webViewDidFinishLoad:`).

Comment: Inserting HTML after loading seems like a hack. Why doesn't UIWebView report the width of the WebView as `device-width`, instead of the width of the device (or at least have an attribute to toggle this behaviour)?