# WKWebView scroll bars

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, ios8

How can I limit to not using horizontal scroll bars on WKWebView?
I am working in objective c.

I need to display a document which is expanding in the webview, and creating a horizontal scroll bar to appear, with the vertical ones.

**Edit:** I have tried setting `contentSize` on `webview.scrollview`, it does restrict the horizontal movement but cuts the document, which is extended out of bounds(and can only be seen when scroll bar is on).

Comment: [self.instanceWKWebView.scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES]; have you tried??

Comment: @rishi that just hides the scroll bar, it does not remove its functionality.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367401/uiwebview-scaling-page-so-that-there-is-no-need-for-horizontal-scrolling