# Change initial scale with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an app with phonegap. I didnt wantet to use media queries because so i had to change all parameters for diffrent viewport sizes. My idea was that i only change the inital scale of the html document with javascript. I know that i can change the initial scale with an function like i show here:

```
 if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 480) {
        document
            .querySelector("meta[name=viewport]")
            .setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=0.4', 'maximum-scale=0.4', 'width=768');
    };
```

but i want that the initial scale is at an width of 320 pixel of the viewport  0 or in other words 100%. And at a viewport width of 720 (Galaxy S3) 110% or in other words initial scale of  0.1. For all the viewport sizes that lay between javascript should calculate the scale. I have no idea how to achieve this! Im very happy about every help! Hope you unterstood me, im from germany!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
 if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 480) { 
    document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute(
          'content', 
          'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
 }
```

Reference : [Can I change the viewport meta tag in mobile safari on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly)

Comment: I wanted to add a missing curly brace but I can't because an edit has to be at least 6 characters :(