# Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to set different Viewports for different android devices. for this i use this piece of code.

```
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.91; maximum-scale=0.91; user-scalable=0;target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />

<script>

if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1)
{
   document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0,target-densityDpi=device-dpi');

} else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {

   document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0');

} else if (window.devicePixelRatio == .78) {

   document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi');

} else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1.5) {

   document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi');

}

</script>

</head>
```

Now problem is that it not setting the appropriate content values. and in Logcat giving this error

> Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.
>
> Viewport argument value "device-width;" for key "width" not recognized. Content ignored.
>
> Viewport argument key ";initial-scale" not recognized and ignored.
>
> Viewport argument value "no;" for key "user-scalable" not recognized. Content ignored.
>
> Viewport argument key "device-dpi" not recognized and ignored.

Any Suggestions. Sorry for the poor editing i am unable to edit it.

EDIT:

At that my Viewport is still not working on android devices.
I want that i should use only one css and tat css should scale images according to the device.

For this i used Viewport with target-dpidensity and gave intial and maximum scale first time it was working but now when i run this approach on android it ignore Viewport.

Actually problem is that when ever i set image in background in html and run this app on any android device it gives image in zoom mood. For this i change my skin html and app.java file and disable zoom mood and also used target-dpidensity but all methods are not working
Here is html code:

[image: html]

Here is css file:

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin: 0;
```

}

div {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 670px;
}

## home {

```
background-image: url('../images/abc_title.png');
width: 1280px;
height: 670px;
```

}

## abc_slide {

```
position: relative; background : transparent;
width: 129px;
height: 76px;
background: transparent; width : 129px; height : 76px;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-left: 80px;
        border: thin;
```

}

## song_slide {

```
position: relative;
background: transparent;
margin-top: 80px;
margin-left: 80px; width : 129px;
height: 76px;
width: 129px;
    border: thin;
```

}

Is its because of droidgap or cordove view

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628

Comment: yes i use same approach but its have errors.

Comment: Did you see the comments on the top-voted answer?

Comment: yes i used both methods but have no effect

Comment: small question. Why are you giving the meta tag an ID if you are not using it?

Comment: Actually id is not included i was just testing through this way. And i am using meta because ibm is multiple platform supporter and i want that my web app run perfectly on all android, BB, iphone and desktop application. at this stage i am testing different html pages.at that time testing my first simple ibm hybrid app on android devices.

Comment: Can you edit your post with how things actually are at this time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to do in general and in the if specificly, but you can remove the meta tag from your HTML and use something like:

```
<script>
    var viewportContent = '';
    if (window.devicePixelRatio = 1) {
        viewportContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi';
    } else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {
        viewportContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0';
    } else if (window.devicePixelRatio == .78) {
        viewportContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi';
    } else if (window.devicePixelRatio == 1.5) {
        viewportContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.51, maximum-scale=0.51, user-scalable=0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi';
    }
    $('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="' + viewportContent + '">');
</script>
```

Comment: thnaks for the help. but at that time Viewport is not working on my android devices

Answer (score 10):

I have solved it by removing the spaces after the comma

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 ">

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that you have to separate the arguments of the viewport-content by "," (as in the answer above) not by ";" (which will be regarded as part of the value and might cause unexpected behaviour)