# Is there an industry standard way to indicate a site has fluid or responsive design?

Tags: css, responsive-design, meta-tags

Is there a meta tag or other flag that would let a browser identify that a site is designed with responsive or fluid layouts vs. a fixed layout?

Trying to determine via client-side feature detection whether a served page has a fluid layout or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along width `@media` queries, the presence of the `viewport` meta tag indicates a responsive site. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

you can check the presence of the viewport tage with js: [Can I change the viewport meta tag in mobile safari on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly)

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing there is a meta tag for it but what you could do is read the style sheet with javascript and find @media screen keyword so you can determine if the site will indeed be responsive here take a look at this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/324533/1287608