# Scale html per screens resolution heightwise and widthwise

Tags: javascript, html, scale

I have built a game from flash to html5 (simple div structure, animations with javascript) which has to fit in one screen so no scroll.

How i can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you give us some code, and an example of what you've tried - we might be able to help.

Comment: This is *very* broad in its current form. Can you show what kind of screen/elements/JS code you have, and how you are running into problems scaling them? (Make sure to provide only the relevant bits though.)

Comment: I have tried to do it with css by having the layout fixed heightwise and then adjusting the inner elements but that is work of years to adjust everything for every pixel of screens so am trying to find an alternative way @thebluefox

Comment: Percentages....

Comment: why don't you fix the scale using css? then just use media queries to adjust the width/height depending on the screen size?

Comment: i can go with that but that will mean to go pixel by pixel for all the screen resolutions from biggest to small @krisph.

Comment: Then set the scale using javascript/jquery after calculating the scale needed with the screen width

Comment: Can you give me an example of how i can calculate the right scale in percentage @krisph?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588628/can-i-change-the-viewport-meta-tag-in-mobile-safari-on-the-fly <-- Look at the following for changing the viewport with javascript, you will need to use somthing like var height = document.body.clientHeight;
var width = document.body.clientWidth; to deterrmin what ratio you need it to be

Comment: Ok but how to know the right css zoom percentage?

Comment: don't quote me on this but say you needed 1000 pixels and the screen was 2000 pixels 2000/1000=2. alternatively you could always set the width and height ratio with the viewport