# Uncaught TypeError on setting attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, scale, viewport

After a lot of research, i finally found how to set the initial scale of a webpage using javascript for example in Chrome DevTools. The code should be like this:

```
document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes");
```

But, I´m always getting error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null(…)` I tried this on different pages. Is there someting that has changed? I found this method in different posts.

Comment: Is there a meta tag with that id? Error is telling you that when that code is run there is no element found with such an id. Show relevant html

Comment: The meta tag has that id?, try `document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]').setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes");`

Comment: Why are you asking us? Inspect it's source

Comment: @ Gerardo: I tried this on google.com. Same error.

Comment: @charlietfl: really relevant html would be [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that there is no element with an id of `"viewport"` on the page.  You may be looking to modify the attributes on the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) instead, in which case [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094906/7043672) describes the right approach using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you (both) very much. It working. Calling `document.getElementById("viewport");`, the viewport-content has changed. However, the scale doesn´t change. What I was trying to achieve, is something like `document.body.style.zoom = '0.8';` on [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/) website. (changing the scale instantly. But if I call zoom, the sliders of the timeintervall selector aren´t working anymore. But I guess, this question here is answered.

Answer (score 1):

I tried first using `document.getElementById("viewport");` and later, using your full code and it worked.

*Here is the screenshot result:*

[image: sample screenshot results]

So, maybe try this. Call `document.getElementById("viewport");` and if if is not null or undefined, execute:

```
document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes");
```

Comment: Thank you (both) very much. It working. Calling `document.getElementById("viewport");`, the viewport-content has changed. However, the scale doesn´t change. What I was trying to achieve, is something like `document.body.style.zoom = '0.8';` on [this](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/) website. (changing the scale instantly. But if I call zoom, the sliders of the timeintervall selector aren´t working anymore. But I guess, this question here is answered. –